# What is the minimum access requirement of rebus?

Tags: rebus

As part of security concern, we manually created msmq queues instead of relying on the automated queue creation from rebus. So what would be the minimum queue access right for rebus queues?

Is full control really necessary?

Thanks

Yin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Rebus starts up, it will automatically create the necessary input queue and error queue (if it's local) if they're not there.

If they're already there, it will check whether the queues are transactional because it cannot live up to its message delivery guarantees if they're non-transactional.

When you create the queues manually, only the transactionality check will be performed - other than that, the only operations performed are send/receive operations.

I'm not an expert on MSMQ access rights, so all I can say is that if a) the transactionality check can be performed, and b) appropriate send/receive access rights are in place (depending on specific endpoints/queues, obviously, then everything should work ok.